# Overlapping Image in a responsive container ( object-fit or bgimage )

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have an overlapping image in a responsive container.

The image should fill out the container even if its overlapping.

I can't achieve it with negative margin since it won't stretch to the top then, is it even possible without js or is the approach completely wrong?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1200px;
}

.c-hero {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: green;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.c-hero__image {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
.c-hero__item {
  align-self: center;
  width: 50%;
}
.c-hero__quote {
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-hero">
    <img class="c-hero__image" src="https://snag.gy/mZNKqJ.jpg">
  <div class="c-hero__item">
    <p class="c-hero__quote">quote</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1200px;
}

.c-hero {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: green;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.c-hero__image {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
  z-index: 0;
}
.c-hero__item {
  align-self: center;
  width: 50%;
}
.c-hero__quote {
  font-size: 36px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-hero">
    <img class="c-hero__image" src="https://snag.gy/mZNKqJ.jpg">
  <div class="c-hero__item">
    <p class="c-hero__quote">quote</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice, but if i try to have the image only fill the left half of the hero header it kills the responsiveness somehow ...